# parameterized-remote-trigger is throwing 405 exception

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to trigger a job A(this is configured as trigger remote) remotely from another job B, and job B needs to hold until results come back to show success or failure, I initially tried using rest API using curl command, it perfectly works.here's the curl code:

curl -v -X POST 'https://xxx.xxx/xxx-xxx/job/xxx/job/master/buildWithParameters?config_files=./jenkins/unit-tests.json' --user xxxx:110f4dfa33ba8f8ef5d8d299beb6aa1543

I choose parameterized plugin code which installed on Jenkins server because it handles the polling mechanism internally and also has handler friendly methods. please see below code for remoteJob, but it fails with **405** error, that means method not allowed in HTTP language, looks like plugin is using ***GET*** method instead of post. I added an option for logging , but it does not seems to be showing more log.

def handle = triggerRemoteJob(
remoteJenkinsName: 'remote-master',
job: 'https://xxx.xxx.com/xxx-xxx/job/xxx/job/master/buildWithParameters',
remoteJenkinsUrl: 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx-xxx/job/xxx/job/master/buildWithParameters',
auth: TokenAuth(apiToken: hudson.util.Secret.fromString('110f4dfa33ba8f8ef5d8d299beb6aa1543'), userName: 'xxxx'),
parameters: 'config_files=./jenkins/unit-tests')

**I am getting following error -**

[Pipeline] triggerRemoteJob
##########################################################################
Parameterized Remote Trigger Configuration:
- job:                     https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx-xxx/job/xxx/job/master/buildWithParameters
- remoteJenkinsUrl:        https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx-xxx/job/ius/job/master/buildWithParameters
- auth:                    'Token Authentication' as user 'sseri'
- parameters:              [config_files=./jenkins/unit-tests]
- blockBuildUntilComplete: true
- connectionRetryLimit:    5
- trustAllCertificates:    false
##########################################################################
Connection to remote server failed [405], waiting to retry - 10 seconds until next attempt. URL: https://xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx-xxx/job/xxx/job/master/buildWithParameters/api/json, parameters:
Retry attempt #1 out of 5

Please help me in this regard!

Comment: could you write your question, explanation, what you did for fix and etc clearly?

Comment: I did not solved the issue, thats why I posted the question here

Comment: Sorry, I meant please explain How you tried with code snippet with more details.

Comment: do you have any idea why 405 is throwing?

Comment: Srinivas, The question is unclear, because of this, it's hard to explain why is the error is for. Please edit and tell what you are looking for, what you have tried etc...

Comment: I added more explanation in my question, can you please let me know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the plugins you are using, but it's quite simple to implement this scenario "call a downstream job from upstream and fail upstream if the downstream fail" without any plugins.

Take a look at my example below.

let say if you have 2 jobs called jobA and jobB and your goal is to call jobB from jobA and fail the jobA if jobB fail.

**Scripted Pipeline for jobA **

```
node() {
  try {
    def jobB = build(job: jobName,parameters: [string(name:"parameterName",value: "parameterValue")])
    def jobBStatus = jobB.getResult()

    if(jobBStatus == "failed") {
      throw new RuntimeException("Downstream job-b failed with reason ...");
    }
    ...
  }catch(Exception e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

**Declarative Pipeline for jobA**

```
pipeline {
  agent any;
  stages {
    stage('call jobB') {
       steps {
           script {
               def jobB = build(job: jobName,parameters: [
                   string(name:"parameterName",value: "parameterValue")
               ])
               def jobBStatus = jobB.getResult()

               if(jobBStatus == "failed") {
                 error("Downstream job-b failed with reason ...")
               }
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response Samit, I did made changes before I read your response as I realize job A and B are in same jenkins server and this build function will work, but my requirement is now I need to call B and C(on different server) from A, I am able to curl it but I need to parse the response and read the build pipeline url with queue number to poll it until it final result comes back

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [Parameterized-Remote-Trigger-Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin). It should give you what you want. I'm having some problems configuring it using authentication tokens and users using Jenkinsfile but if you are using the GUI im sure you will get the job done.